# Dapper.net dynamic OR query

Tags: dapper

New to using Dapper and need a little help.  I have a .csv file that I will read to dynamically generate a select statement.

The .csv file contents look like this:

```
id,fromDate,toDate
1,20100101,20110101
2,20110101,20120101
3,20100101,20120101
etc...
```

The query I need to dynamically generate should be:

```
SELECT * FROM targetTable WHERE (id = 1 AND cDate BETWEEN 20100101 AND 20110101) OR (id = 2 AND cDate BETWEEN 20110101 AND 20120101) OR 
OR (id = 3 AND cDate BETWEEN 20100101 AND 20120101)
```

How can I do this with Dapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply building your query?

Assuming you have all your data in this form after reading the csv and push it into classes:

```
public class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FromDate { get; set; }
    public int ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

I'd just simply pass the query string:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
foreach (var data in listData) // listData ... List<Data>
{
    string line = string.Format("(id = {0} and cdate between {1} and {2})", data.ID,data.FromDate, data.ToDate);
    lines.Add(line);
}

string additionalQuery = string.Join(" OR ", myLines);
```

and then...

```
var result = sqlConnection.Query<MyQueryData>(string.Format("SELECT * FROM targetTable WHERE {0}", additionalQuery));
```

Will work just fine...

Comment: Thanks!  I am a newbie to using Dapper and I wasn't sure if there was a better way to build the query.